# Setting graph attributes in qqmath from the lattice package?

Tags: r, lattice

Can anyone tell me how to set attributes within `qqmath` from the `lattice` package. Specifically how do I increase the font size of axis titles, axis text etc? None of the native `plot` arguments seem to work.

```
library(lattice)

lattice::qqmath(~ rnorm(100), distribution = function(p) qt(p, df = 10),
               id=0.05,
               main = "this is a title",
               ylab = "this is a y-axis",
               xlab = "this is an x-axis",
               cex = 2,
               cex.axis = 4,
               font = 2,
               cex.lab = 4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution in the labyrinth that is the help page for `lattice`. In order to specify attributes of axis labels in lattice graphs you need to use the `x` and `y` argument within the `scales` argument, all wrapped in `list()`. To change the font size of titles you also need to wrap everything in a `list()`:

```
lattice::qqmath(~ rnorm(100), distribution = function(p) qt(p, df = 10),
               id=0.05,
               main = list("this is a title", cex = 2),
               ylab = list("this is a y-axis", cex = 3),
               xlab = list("this is an x-axis", cex = 4),
               scales = list(x = list(cex = 4)))
```